# 4 Way Switch circuit, all switch terminals are hot in certain configurations

Tags: electrical

I have a circuit in my home that has 3 switches controlling a light in a switch loop configuration with two 3 way switches and a 4 way switch in between them (black, white and red wires).

The switches work as expected in each of the 8 possible switch position combinations. My question is that for 3/4 of the combinations where the light illuminates, every terminal on each one of the switches is hot. Why would this be the case I was not expecting this. I have a second similar circuit in my home that does the same thing.

Can anyone help explain? Thank you.

Comment: Your readings are faulty.  You're reading "phantom voltage" on the wires which are disconnected at both ends owing to the switch states.  They are getting capacitively coupled to the other hot wires in the cable, and causing your too-sensitive voltmeter to misread. A lower impedance voltmeter would read a correct value.

Comment: Okay so my cheapo voltage tester with the light is just pickup up voltage nearby in the box? What would an example of a low impedance voltmeter be?

Comment: There's detectable voltage on the cable, a cheap sensitive DVM will also detect it (but read it as slightly lower voltage).  A lower impedance voltmeter would be a DVM marked as low impedance, or an analog meter.  The phantom voltage does not have enough electro-motive force to move the needle on an analog meter.

Comment: You don't say what hot is, but phantom voltage is usually below 100v, not the normal ~120v.  A test for phantom voltage is using an incandescent light bulb.  Phantom voltage will not light it up, real voltage will light it up.  Saves fingers/tongues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.